# Setting up cron to run every 30 minutes

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

I want to create a cron that runs every 30 minutes.

I am using another cron as an example - I have created the cron in a `config.xml` file, not using the admin interface.

The example I am using is the following:

```
<tracking_cron>
    <schedule><cron_expr>0 4 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run>
        <model>tracking/observer::cron</model>
    </run>
</tracking_cron>
```

My questions are as follows:

1) On what intervals is the above cron being run?

2) What would the `cron_expr` be for a cron that should run every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Current cron expression you have added `<cron_expr>0 4 * * *</cron_expr>` will run every day at 04:00 AM

```
next at 2017-03-23 04:00:00
then at 2017-03-24 04:00:00
then at 2017-03-25 04:00:00
then at 2017-03-26 04:00:00
then at 2017-03-27 04:00:00
```

If You want it for every 30 minutes you can add expression as

`<cron_expr>*/30 * * * *</cron_expr>`

```
next at 2017-03-22 14:30:00
then at 2017-03-22 15:00:00
then at 2017-03-22 15:30:00
then at 2017-03-22 16:00:00
then at 2017-03-22 16:30:00
```

You can test expression from this [reference site](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: I bookmarked that site, it's exactly what I needed - I searched extensively but nowhere coudl I actually find anything that explained it to me, than you very much!